# Why data is displayed without spaces?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some trouble.In my application I use `ListView`, each element is `list_item.xml`.    I get som data from server and fills `listView`. The problem is that the data are displayed without spaces between them. Although the `designer` in  android studio, everything is displayed correctly with all formattng.
My code `list_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">


        <TextView

            android:text="123"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_employee_id"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:divider="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <TextView
            android:text="Ivan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_employee_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:divider="#ffffff"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <TextView
            android:text="Ivanoff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_employee_last_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:divider="#ffffff"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my listViewXML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffaac4ee"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ff7b9fee"
 >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">


            <TextView

                android:text="№"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/id"

                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:divider="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
          />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.4">

            <TextView
                android:text="Имя"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:divider="#ffffff"
                android:textAlignment="center" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_weight="0.4">



            <TextView
                android:text="Фамилия"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:divider="#ffffff"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffaac4ee"
 >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change ListView attributes to

```
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and its works!

Comment: There are some things you should change in your code, namely changing android:layout_*="fill_parent" to android:layout_*="0dp". Where * is the orientation you want to add the weight to (appears to be height for you). Also either add your old ListView xml, else this question is irrelevant for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code by gravity:
try this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:weightSum="1">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">


    <TextView

        android:text="123"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_employee_id"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <TextView
        android:text="Ivan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_employee_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <TextView
        android:text="Ivanoff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_employee_last_name"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:divider="#ffffff"

        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```